# android call stack interpretation

Tags: java, android

```
Thread [<3> main] (Suspended (breakpoint at line 12 in MyContentView))
MyContentView.onDraw(Canvas) line: 12
MyContentView(View).draw(Canvas) line: 6535
FrameLayout(ViewGroup).drawChild(Canvas, View, long) line: 1531
FrameLayout(ViewGroup).dispatchDraw(Canvas) line: 1258
FrameLayout(View).draw(Canvas) line: 6538
```

What do those in brackets mean? e.g. `FrameLayout(ViewGroup)` and `FrameLayout(View)`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
FrameLayout(ViewGroup).dispatchDraw(Canvas) line: 1258
```

dispatchDraw method inherited from ViewGroup is getting called.

```
FrameLayout(View).draw(Canvas) line: 6538
```

draw(..) inherited method from View class is getting called